# File Comparision in Unix for Huge Files

Tags: file, unix

I have two files in Unix Box, both have around 10 million rows.

File1 (Only one column)
ASD123
AFG234

File2 (Only one column)
ASD456
AFG234

Now I want to compare the records from File 1 to File 2 and output those that are in File2. How to achieve this?

I have tried a while loop and grep, seems it is way too slow, any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the rows from file A which are also in file B, you can use `grep`'s inbuilt `-f` option:

```
grep -Ff fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

This should be faster than putting it inside any kind of loop (although given the size of your files, it may still take some time).